# Parrot OS comes with node version 12.0 by default, but I could not install the latest nodejs package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, parrot-os

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (12.22.12~dfsg-1~deb11u3).
```

Since node 12.X isn't the latest version, how do I update it?

When I try to run my Ionic application, I get an error message

```
└──╼ $ionic serve
> ng run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[ng] Node.js version v12.22.12 detected.
[ng] The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.13 or v18.10.
[ng] Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 3).
        
        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

On reboot, if the greater version was successfully installed, it reverts to the default version

Answer (score 2):

I used nvm(node version manager) to manage all my node versions (**you should too**) and I installed it like this under Parrot OS (it is similar to other Systems).

Remove old nodejs and npm if installed:

1. `sudo apt remove -y npm`
2. `sudo apt remove -y nodejs`

Create .bashrc if it does not exists. For me there was only the .zshrc by default on Parrot OS.

3. `touch ~/.bashrc`

Get nvm via curl:

4. `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash`
5. `source ~/.bashrc`

Install Node with nvm:

6. `nvm install node` (installs the latest stable version)

Check if you have the version you like. Type `nvm` if you wanna see how to install or switch to other versions.

7. `node --version`

Now run your ng command again to check if it works.